# Salesforce how to return custom error object

Tags: soap, salesforce

I've written the following Apex class as a part of a suite of custom webservices. All have the same problem but this one is the easiest example; if I can solve it for this, I can solve it for the other webservices.

```
global class WebServiceA4S {
     global class returngetEnquiries {
        public String status {get;set;}
        public String error {get;set;}
        public List<Enquiry__c> results {get;set;}
    }

    Webservice static returngetEnquiries  getEnquiries() { 
        returngetEnquiries rtnError = new returngetEnquiries();
        rtnError.status='success';
        rtnError.error = '';
        rtnError.results = new List<Enquiry__c>();
        // id en name
        try {
            list<Enquiry__c> tmp = [Select id,name From Enquiry__c];
            rtnError.results = tmp;
        } 
         catch(Exception e) {
             rtnError.status='error';
             rtnError.error = String.valueof(e);

         }


     return rtnError;
        }
}
```

Now if I debug the rtnError returned, just before the 'return rtnError', it does show a list of Enquiries so the code works.
The problem is that if I call the Webservice (via PHP or SOAPUI) the result is empty.
I use the wsdl from the class, created by salesforce of course.

I also looked at the wsdl and it looks like this:

```
...
<xsd:complexType name="returngetEnquiries">
    <xsd:sequence/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="getEnquiries">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="getEnquiriesResponse">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="result" type="tns:returngetEnquiries" nillable="true"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
...
```

It looks like the returngetEnquiries is not defined. I tried to edit it and add the fields as defined in the class, but that doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately popping out as wrong... But do you really have to capture errors like that (regardless of the fact that SELECT will rarely throw anything)? If you'll leave simple `return [SELECT...];`, thrown exception will bubble up and return to you XML response that SOAP library on your side should interpret and cast an exception within PHP too... Like outcome of http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.fault.php

Comment: You are absolutely right about throwing the error. However, this is done in preparation for building some more logic in there. But first I would like to get _some_ results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigating I found the solution. It is in the returnclass. The parameters should be webservice instead of public:

```
global class returngetEnquiries {
    webservice String status {get;set;}
    webservice String error {get;set;}
    webservice List<Enquiry__c> results {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Cool, good to know :) Would you mind accepting your own answer so it goes "off the radar"?